# "It is okay to have fun however think about others" translation

Tags: translation

I want to say :

It is okay to have fun at new year's eve ,however think about others.

The only part that I was able to translate is :

おしょうがつにたのしみますだいじょうぶでも.....

and I can't complete.

The situation is that people at new year's eve throw their old stuff,beer bottles,garbage,etc.. in the streets. The next day it becomes very hard for the street cleaners to clean that mess so it is kind of sad. 
I want to write that it is okay to have fun at that day however be considerate to others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could say:

> [大晦日]{おおみそか}を[楽]{たの}しく[過]{す}ごすのは(or 大晦日に[盛]{も}り[上]{あ}がるのは) いいですが(or [結構]{けっこう}ですが*)、([少]{すこ}しは)[他人]{たにん}(or [人]{ひと} or [他]{ほか}の[人]{ひと}) のことも[考]{かんが}えてください。or (少しは)[人]{ひと}の[迷惑]{めいわく}も考えてください。

if you want it in the polite form.
*結構ですが would sound a bit sarcastic.

(I might say 少しは人の迷惑も考えろ！if I was very angry.)

Comment: 私なら「人への迷惑」と言いますが、ググったら「人の迷惑」の方が多いみたいですね！面白い！